# running gcloud command on a bash file on windows

Tags: gcloud

Is there a way to automatically execute the command of starting a instance and connect to it via ssh when I launch the google cloud sdk shell ? How to do ? I was thinking about a bash file which will be executed automatically and wich will also contains the 2 commands.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

I have found [another question](https://superuser.com/questions/144347/is-there-windows-equivalent-to-the-bashrc-file-in-linux) in superuser that tries to solve your problem. Specifically, from [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/144349) we can extract that you should be able to modify your shortcut to execute a `.bat` file.

Therefore you should create a script, that should be something in the lines of:

```
@echo off
gcloud compute instances start <instance_name>
gcloud compute ssh <instance_name>
```

Don't forget to read the documentation of both operations and make sure they work in your scenario:

- [gcloud compute instances start](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/start)
- [gcloud compute ssh](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh)